# ProxyPass: discard body data

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I have some rules like

```
<Location /xyz>
    ProxyPass http://example.com/abc
    ...
</Location>
```

I want to accept requests to http://mypage.lan/xyz/123 and deliver the data of http://example.com/abc/123. I need to accept POST request, but I don't want to send the body content to example.com. I would like to send a GET request, but a POST request with *Content-Length: 0* would be fine, too.

Is it possible, to configure Apache 2 not to promote the request body?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible for the body data to be modified in this way by Apache (or to proxy a different method than received).  The most modification that it can do is to tweak headers.

I'd question the need for a web service that behaves in this way (just send the right request from the client?), but if you do need to do this, consider using application code running within Apache that modifies the request in the needed  ways and creates its own request to the backend server.

Comment: I mean that you could use application code like PHP, perl, or python that can run within Apache, not an Apache module.